# ag-grid agTextColumnFilter defaultOption

Tags: ag-grid-ng2

I have to set default value to ag-grid agTextColumnFilter.
I order to do that I I added filterParams and defaultOption, but the filter does't works after my changes.

```
gridOptions = {
    enableFilter: true,
    ...
    columnDefs: [
        {headerName: "Status", field: "status", filter: "agTextColumnFilter", 
        filterParams: { defaultOption: { notContains: 'default text'} }  }
    ]
}
```

I am using this documentation.
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-text/

Answer (score 2):

Just do this when you are pushing data in ag-grid

```
columnData.push({
              headerName: "Site Name", 
              field: "siteName",
              dataType: "string",
              enableValue: true,
              filter: "agTextColumnFilter",
              editable: false,
            });
```